# How to convert System.Drawing.Color to Microsoft Interop WdColorIndex

Tags: c#, colors, ms-word

How can I convert `System.Drawing.Color` to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex`?

I have done the code so far, but it's showing the error "overflow".

Here is the code which I have done

```
Color bgcolor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(innerText));
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex wbgc = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex)(bgcolor.R + 0x100 * bgcolor.G + 0x10000 * bgcolor.B);
doc.Range(iRangeStart, iRangeEnd).HighlightColorIndex = wbgc;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is (Convert.ToInt32(innerText)); looking to convert?

Comment: The innerText will contain the value something like this "-55582212"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WdColorIndex` is an enumeration, not an object that defines a color system. This means that the value you can assign is limited by the enumeration elements, e.g. `wdBlack` or `wdBlue` and their underlying integer values.

The technique you are using is to be applied to a `WdColor` object instead of a `WdColorIndex` enumeration:

```
var wordColor = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor)(bgcolor.R + 0x100 * bgcolor.G + 0x10000 * bgcolor.B);
```

Highlighting in a Word document is limited to a number of colors, as defined in the `WdColorIndex` enumeration. Therefore, you cannot simply convert any color to a Word color for highlighting. You have to pick one of the available values. See [MSDN for WdColorIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdcolorindex.aspx) for possible values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.                                 I want to highlight the text using the above code . To highlight the text i think we have to use the the "HighlightColorIndex" property. or is there any other way to Highlight the text in Microsoft.Office.Interop?

Comment: JPaul, I have edited my answer to include highlighting in Word.

Comment: Thank you John. Now i understood that i just can't convert directly my InnerText value. I need to pick one color According to the wdcolor index. do you have any sample code for Highlighting the text using interop? As i have no much experience in using Microsoft office interop. Thank you once again for the valid suggestion.i wasted my lot of time by trying to convert.

Comment: [This CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/220074/Search-and-Highlight-the-Text-in-Word-through-Csha) example has C# code that you can use to get started, and you're welcome!

Comment: Can you explain what you did in (bgcolor.R + 0x100 * bgcolor.G + 0x10000 * bgcolor.B). Did you create a hexValue ?